# Cookie pass between .Net API and Blazor server

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, cookies, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing a test app to pass a cookie between a Web API and a Blazor Server App. I have tried multiple ways to get the cookie to come back to the application but it never is in the cookie section on any browser.

This is the API method.

```
[HttpGet("test-cookie")]
public IActionResult TestCookie()
{
    Response.Cookies.Append("SimpleTestCookie", "TestValue", new CookieOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = true,
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
    });
    return Ok("Test cookie set");
}
```

This is the `program.cs` file. (A lot of this was suggested by chat for testing purposes.)

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44319") 
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowCredentials();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication("TestName")
    .AddCookie("TestName", options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Cookie.Name = "TestCookie";
        options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
........
CookiePolicyOptions options = new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified
};
app.UseCookiePolicy(options);
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");
```

Inside my Blazor Server App I am using

`var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44367/Test/TestCookie/test-cookie");`

The API is hit correctly from the Blazor App since I am able to debug through the API. On the return the set cookie attribute is present. I have tested in Postman and it returns the cookie correctly.

How do I get the cookie to return to the Blazor app and save inside the cookies of the browser?

Comment: The request from the Blazor app must be made with the `credentials` property set to `include`. Check if your `httpClient` is configured to send credentials. could you check the browser section does it shows the cookie in it. check for the `Set-Cookie` header in the response from your API.try testing the site in the incognito mode. make sure browser is not using the strict security policy setting and  "Block third-party cookies" is not enabled. also check the console logs.

Comment: Blazor Server uses a long-running SignalR connection to pass data back and forth between client and server, so you shouldn't need to make HTTP calls at all. Are you using the right tool for the job? You can set cookies with JS interop.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal When I look at the HttpResponse the Set-Cookie Header is included inside the response. The value of it is: SimpleTestCookie=TestValue; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly

Comment: @MateusZampol The long running SingnalR is between Blazor Server and the Blazor front in right? I am trying to access an API from the Blazor server side to get information from a database and save it in a cookie for later use. What would be a better approach to this if cookie is not that the best option? The Blazor application does not have access to the database.

Comment: @runemonster You should write your DB call in a service class and inject it in your razor component. The code is executed on the server side. After the service call you can use JS interop to save the info to a cookie or to local storage.

Comment: @MateusZampol If I am understadnign correctly. Are you saying make a third class that is not a Blazor file inside the Blazor project that calls the API and gets the return. Then save the response header cookie inside that same class to the browser and finally return back to the Blazor file with if it was successful or not so the next step can happen? Do you have any example of that?

Comment: @runemonster Better yet, you should read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server#aspnet-core-protected-browser-storage). The framework already implements client side storage for you. Just call the API or DB wherever you want and use this class to save the information you need to the browser.

Comment: @MateusZampol Ok I read through this and I have a brief understanding of what it does. So using this approach I would not need the Response.Cookies.Append in the API right? I would need to make an API call that gets the information I want to save and then save it in Blazor client side storage. Then I can access it all over the Blazor application.

Comment: Sorry for the late response I could not get that to work so I switched to using JWT tokens and all worked great. Just a little more coding.